# How do I find cos(x/2) without a calculator?

Tags: trigonometry

Using this figure:

[image: A right triangle with a = 12 and b = 5]

Solve without a calculator:

$$
\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}
$$

I know the hypotenuse is 13 but what do I do next?

Comment: Are you familiar with any trigonometric identities?

Comment: Please see [Half-angle formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Half-angle_formulae).

Comment: Do you know the double angle formula $\cos 2x = 2\cos^2x - 1$? What happens if you let $\theta = 2x$? The half-angle formulae are mentioned above, but they're just the double-angle formulae in thin disguise.

Comment: Extend the adjacent side $12$ to the right to length $13$. Join the new endpoint with the top corner, and find its length. Now there's an isosceles triangle with apex $\theta$ and known side lengths; the angle bisector from the apex is also the perpendicular bisector of the base.

Comment: But then, where in the question is it given that the $12$ and $5$ sides are perpendicular?

Comment: @peterwhy If you are not allowed to assume a right triangle, then $~\theta~$ is undetermined.  Further, $~5^2 + 12^2~$ happens to be a perfect square.  Finally, it is very common for problem composers to be careless.

Comment: Where in the question is it given that the 12 and
5 sides are perpendicular?  Where the OP says "I know the  hypotenuse is 13".

Comment: @peterwhy my mistake. It is a right triangle.

Comment: @user2661923 not careless. I faithfully reproduced the problem as it was put to me on an assignment ;)

Comment: You misinterpreted my comment.  It is the original problem composer who was careless, for not specifying that it is a right triangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the given figure looks like a right-angled triangle,and the question-asker also have used this(he/she knows the hypotenuse is 13),so I also do the problem taking it a right-angled triangle.

---

Hope you know the formula :
$$\cos 2x=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x =2\cos^2 x-1$$

Putting $2x=\theta ,$

$$\cos \theta =2\cos^2 \frac\theta 2-1$$
$$\Rightarrow
\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}{2}}
$$

Now,you know the hypotenuse is 13 ,and the traingle is right-angled,$$\therefore \cos \theta=\frac {\text{base} }{\text{hypotenuse}}=\frac {12}{13}$$

$$\therefore \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}{2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1+\frac {12}{13}}{2}}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{25}{26}}=\pm\frac 5{\sqrt{26}}$$

---

Since $\cos \theta >0$,so $\theta$ is in 1st or 4th quadrant.

- If $\theta$ is in 1st quadrant,let $\theta \in $ $[0,\frac π2]$, so $\frac{\theta} 2$ in 1st quadrant also.$\therefore \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}>0$ .
- If $\theta$ is in 4th quadrant, let $\theta \in [\frac{3π}2 ,2π]$,so $\frac{\theta} 2$ in 2nd quadrant .
  $\therefore \cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}<0.$

Comment: You may comment on choosing the positive square root.

Comment: Oops, yeah it was a right-angled triangle. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

**Proof without words**
[image]

$$
\cos \frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{5}{\sqrt{26}} 
$$
Wish it helps!

Comment: "Proof without words" That is not true, because there are words. +1 nice proof anyway.

Comment: You need to justify that extending the base by $13$ makes the angle $\frac {\theta}2$.  I could make the same diagram and replace $13$ by $1000$, calculate the new long hypotenuse, and get the wrong answer.

Comment: @Ross Millikan If you replaced $13$ with $1000,$ then $\ \Delta ABD\ $ would no longer be isosceles. "Proof without words" seems like a fair enough description to me.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera:  it seems to me some words to explain that the $5 \sqrt{26}$ comes from the fact that the triangle is isosceles would be valuable.  I didn't see that on my reading.

Comment: @Ross Millikan I didn't get the $\ 5\sqrt{26}\ $   from the isosceles triangle but the right-angled triangle whose other sides are $\ 5\ $ and $\ 12+13=25\ .$ I don't entirely disagree with your point about the angle $\ \frac{\theta}{2}\ ,$ though.  Whether this needs explicit justification I think depends a lot on who the audience is, and here on *Mathematics Stack Exchange* there are almost certainly readers who would benefit from a brief explanation of why it has that value.

Comment: I think I figured out where the $\frac{\theta}{2}$ comes from:

$$
\angle ABD = 180° - \theta
$$
$$
\angle DAB = 180° - \angle ABD - \angle ADB
$$
$$
\angle ADB = \angle DAB
$$
$$
\angle DAB = 180° - (180° - \theta) - \angle DAB
$$
$$
2\angle DAB = \theta
$$
$$
\angle DAB = \theta/2
$$

Comment: The teacher expects to solve with trig identities so I gotta go with @MathSolver's answer. Still a neat proof.